# Firebase db listener isn't invoked when db's child is added

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-database

I added the user object to firebase db in Android client, and I can see the result in firebase console.

```
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("users");
ref.child(user.getUid()).setValue(mUser);
```

In backend - node.js, firebase db reference listen 'child_added' event, But it never invoked, and I can't see any logs.

```
var db = firebase.database();
var ref = db.ref("users");

ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey){
  console.log("child_added: " + snapshot);
});
```

In case of adding user in node.js server side, the listener is called.

```
ref.child("user1").set("user1");
```

I didn't set any db rules and securities.
Why listener isn't called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue after I remove the service account parameter in initializeApp of node.js side.